# Saving multiple files types into one file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm developing a 3D application in which the user may load multiple images, the 3D library I use has a function to export the whole scene as XAML, of course in XAML I only have the path to the images, so the file will only be valid on the machine in which it has been created, what I want to do is to save the XAML , change image(s) path inside the XAML to be relative to the XAML file path, save image(s) along the XAML in the same new file, like this the new file will always contain the XAML and the images. how to save multiple files types within the same file ? any other suggestions on the whole idea would be appreciated.

Comment: you may save all in a zip file

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I was considering this, but then when I unzip it to reload the files into my app, of course I only want to do that in memory, how the relative images paths inside the XAML would work ?

Comment: Why memory, you can unzip relevant files into a temp folder and delete them after you have done with them.

Comment: thanks for the advice , you may summarize all this in one answer, I will mark it as the right answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Store your XAML and other image files into one file (e.g. zip or cab).
2. When running your program, unzip relevant file into a temp folder so you can get the relevant path working.
3. Empty the temp folder afterwards if required.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.5, then you can programmatically save multiple files into a zip folder easily using the new [`ZipFile` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First, you'll need to prepare your files into a new folder (`Directory.CreateDirectory`, `File.Move`) and then you can simply use the [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (adapted from the linked page):

```
string filePathOfNewFolder = @"c:\example\start";
string zipFilePath = @"c:\example\result.zip";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filePathOfNewFolder, zipFilePath);
```

---

UPDATE >>>

For .NET 4, you might have to rely more on third party libraries. You can download the `DotNetZip` library from the [DotNetZip - Zip and Unzip in C#, VB, any .NET language](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) page on CodePlex.  It also works fairly simply. Here is an example taken from the linked page:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
    zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
    // add the report into a different directory in the archive
    zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
    zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
    zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm using 4.0